# link href with image onclick jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an `<a>` and div control for pop up window function. The popup is working correctly. I want to set an image click to open the alert pop up, i.e. on image click I want to redirect to href action. My code is the following:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div> <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

         <h2>Timesheet Comments</h2>

        <input type="text" class="TxtNotess" onchange="GetChange" />
        <input type="button" class="BtnComment" value="Save" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I have some CSS code to handle the popup, and now I want to use an image and try to call the href action on click event of image

```
<img src="~/Images/comment.png" class="testmy" />                       
    <a href="#openModal">
</a>

$('.testmy').click(function() {
        alert('hi');
        $('#openModal').click();
    });
```

Comment: Looks like a lot of code, what exactly is the problem here? SO is not here to let other write your code, just help you with specific problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `<a href="#openModal">` and `</a>` *around* the image

```
<a href="#openModal">
    <img src="~/Images/comment.png" class="testmy" />
</a>
```

And remove the javascript code afterwards, that is not needed